# C# Updating DataGridView with List and checkbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a C# program making http requests to a REST API and saving the data into Lists.

I'm just using `DataGridView.DataSource` to populate the DataGridView each 5seconds.

```
private void timerStatusManager_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ControllerListImpressions.AddItemPrinterList();

      PrinterList = ControllerListImpressions.PrinterList;
     // dataGrid.DataSource = null;
      dataGrid.DataSource = PrinterList.Impressions;

      timerStatusManager.Start();
    }
```

The Method `AddItemPrinterList` just updates the List when there is a new item at the request.

`PrinterList.Impressions` is a list defined here:

```
public List<Impression> Impressions = new List<Impression>();
```

My problem is that the `dataGrid` never updates when the List has one new item. When I set `DataSource` to `null` it update correctly, but I have a `CheckBox` at the `DataGridView`. This `CheckBox` always goes to false when the `DataGridView` is updated on that manner.

Comment: Instead of `List<Impression>` use `BindingList<Impression>`

Comment: Even using this peace of code, it does not work.
`var actualList = PrinterList.Impressions;`
`var listBinding = new BindingList<Impression>(actualList);`

Comment: Without a minimal, verifiable example I can't know what is going wrong, but it works, check out this demo: https://github.com/crowcoder/BindingListDemo

Answer (score 0):

Just bind a DataSource to your GridView, and call:

`dataGrid.Refresh()` each time you want it to be refreshed, otherwise the datasource will be updated but not the grid

Comment: It does not work. I do know that the DataSource is being updated, but sadly the GridView is not.

Comment: try call `dataGrid.Refresh()` and `dataGrid.Update()` otherwhise, instead of .Refresh, set the bind again ->`dataGrid.DataSource = PrinterList.Impressions;`

Comment: Actually this bind code is inside a timer, so every 5 seconds it should update the GridView. It just update when I set DataSource to null before the update. In this case, the problem is that my checkboxes are also setted to false, but it should keep its value.

Comment: Can you try using BindingList instead of List?

Comment: I already have tried with BindingList, but it also doesn't work.